# Java android EventBus detect if server is send to phone message

Tags: java, android, event-bus

I want to use a EventBus to detect if server is send something

I register an eventBus :

```
App.getBus().register(this);
public static App getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public static EventBus getBus() {
    return EventBus.getDefault();
}
```

But I don't have idea how I can detect if server is send something

Comment: what do you mean by server?

Comment: @Darish I send a requewst too server to generate a file and send to phone , but I don;t want to do it this in asyn task and I want to send from server message that a file is ready to download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have idea how I can detect if server is send something

EventBus is use used to send events with in the app, it can not be used to send messages from server to client via internet. Sending message from server to client can be implemented by using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) by google.

Comment: It is a open source api ?

Comment: You will be needing some sort of server, restful api implementing FCM (former Google Cloud Messaging).